# Error during turtlebot launch

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, anaconda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run:-

`roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch`

but I am getting following error:-

```
from defusedxml.xmlrpc import monkey_patch
ImportError: No module named defusedxml.xmlrpc
while processing /opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_gazebo/launch/includes/kobuki.launch.xml:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/kinetic/share/xacro/xacro.py '/opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_description/robots/kobuki_hexagons_asus_xtion_pro.urdf.xacro'] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="$(arg urdf_file)" name="robot_description"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278228/error-during-turtlebot-launch/) by [Nebula](https://answers.ros.org/users/33043/nebula/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2017-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What ROS version are you using? Kinetic? I assume you are running it in Ubuntu? Did you do the full install?
Do you have Miniconda or Anaconda installed?

If you answer those questions more help can be provided, since the released packages for turtlebot work with no troubles in Kinetic, I've used them many times.

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nebula](https://answers.ros.org/users/33043/nebula/) on 2017-12-28**:
I did full install of Kinetic.I have Anaconda. Although I solved this problem by pip install defusedxml. Now I can run the simulator but I got `[ERROR] [1514443066.744419842]: Skipped loading plugin with error: XML Document '/opt/ros/kinetic/share/gmapping/nodelet_plugins.xml' has no Root Element`